# How to tell the mass dimensions of couplings and fields in zero dimensional QFTs?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dimensional-analysis

Consider the zero dimensional QFT given by the action
$$
I=\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2
$$
I want to somehow be able to tell the mass dimensions of the fields and the couplings. Nonetheless, From the action above I do not see how I could accomplish this, since the lack of the kinetic term leaves an ambiguity on the mass dimension of the field. So, is it ambiguous, and if not, how can you tell it?

Comment: Mass dimension is just the inverse of spatial dimension. There is no spatial dimension in 0d QFT, thus I suspect that there is no mass dimension. Could you clarify what you mean by "mass dimension" here maybe?

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus you are right. Hadn't reflected on that. I guess they are just numbers after all.

Comment: $[I]=0\Leftrightarrow[\phi]=-1$... (note also that $[\phi]=(d-2)/2$ for $d\ge2$, which you can extrapolate down to $d=0$)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform well for $d > 0$ there's a kinetic term in the action which doesn't contain $m$, from which the dimensions of $[\phi] = d / 2 - 1$ and $m = 1$ can be deduced. Here the situation is different. $m$ is just a number, no restriction is posed on $[m]$ by the theory. So my point is: it might not make sense to extrapolate down to $d = 0$.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus sure. But whatever $[m]$ is, we must have $[I]=0$ and therefore $[\phi]=[m](d-2)/2$, so we call "$(d-2)/2$" the "mass-dimension" of $\phi$, even if $m$ is not actually a mass. Of course, it is all a matter of convention, but having to choose one, $[\phi]=-1$ seems to be the most natural convention.